# String permutations rank + data structure

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, permutation

The problem at hand is:

> Given a string. Tell its rank among all its permutations sorted
>   lexicographically.

The question can be attempted mathematically, but I was wondering if there was some other algorithmic method to calculate it ?

Also if we have to store all the string permutations rankwise , how can we **generate** them efficiently (and what would be the complexity) . What would be a **good data structure** for storing the permutations and which is also efficient for retrieval?

EDIT

Thanks for the detailed answers on the permutations generation part, could someone also suggest a good data structure? I have only been able to think of trie tree.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: http://www.algopill.com/2011/03/13/lexicographic-permutations-iterative/ - this approach would avoid needing to store the permutations (as they are already ordered) and instead just test for string equality at each step.

Comment: @Gian : what would be the complexity of the algo ?

Comment: you should be able to calculate the rank. are the elements of the string unique unique? i.e. is "122333" legal input?

Comment: No , it is not necessary that the elements of the string will be unique. Yes it is legal.

Comment: @user1416970 that will make it harder to calculate the rank. if you can afford the memory, just keep a sorted array around and look it up using a binary search.

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving some guidance on the generation part , can someone also comment on the data structure part ?

Comment: Permutations can be encoded compactly in factorial base: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

Comment: @phs: Nice one , but could you please explain it , I am not sure I understand it fully.

Comment: As is detailed in the link, there is a transformation that takes permutations over a fixed number of objects and maps them to (and from) integers.  By decoding such an integer and applying it to some canonical string (such as the sorted string), you can recover other string permutations.  Note that the encoded integer may still end up being large; taking it to be a byte vector may be more realistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an O(n|Σ|) algorithm to find the rank of a string of length n in the list of its permutations. Here, Σ is the alphabet.

#### Algorithm

Every permutation which is ranked below **s** can be written *uniquely* in the form **pcx**; where:

- **p** is a proper prefix of **s**
- **c** is a character ranked below the character appearing just after **p** in **s**. And **c** is also a character occurring in the part of **s** not included in **p**.
- **x** is *any* permutation of the remaining characters occurring in **s**; i.e. not included in **p** or **c**.

We can count the permutations included in each of these classes by iterating through each prefix of **s** in increasing order of length, while maintaining the frequency of the characters appearing in the remaining part of **s**, as well as the number of permutations **x** represents. The details are left to the reader.

This is assuming the arithmetic operations involved take constant time; which it wont; since the numbers involved can have nlog|Σ| digits. With this consideration, the algorithm will run in O(n<sup>2</sup> log|Σ| log(nlog|Σ|)). Since we can add, subtract, multiply and divide two d-digit numbers in O(dlogd).

#### C++ Implementation

```
typedef long long int lli;

lli rank(string s){
    int n = s.length();

    vector<lli> factorial(n+1,1);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        factorial[i] = i * factorial[i-1];
    
    vector<int> freq(26);
    lli den = 1;
    lli ret = 0;
    for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
        int si = s[i]-'a';
        freq[si]++;
        den *= freq[si];
        for(int c = 0; c < si; c++) 
            if(freq[c] > 0) 
                ret += factorial[n-i-1] / (den / freq[c]);
    }
    return ret + 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't think a lexicographically-lower permutation of **s** need begin with a proper prefix of it.  E.g. suppose **s** = `ba`.  Then `ab` is a lexicographically-lower permutation that doesn't begin with a proper prefix of **s**.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The prefix can be empty too. By a proper prefix, I mean a prefix **p** of **s** which is not equal to the entire string **s**.

Comment: So it can!  It has clicked for me now: +1.

Comment: @bloops: Can you please explain what is `factorial[n-i-1] / (den / freq[c])` doing? I am not able to understand the intuition behind this solution.

Comment: I am using the formula for counting the number of permutations of N characters where some characters may be repeated. Suppose there are S = |\Sigma| types of characters and there are K_1 characters of type 1, K_2 characters of type 2, .... K_S characters of type S.

Then the number of permutations is:
N! / (K_1! K_2! K_3! ... K_S!)

Comment: The "factorial[n-i-1] / (den / freq[c])" step is counting the number of permutations of type 'x' (from the answer.).

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to the [quickselect algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). In an unsorted array of integers, find the index of some particular array element. The partition element would be the given string.

Edit:

Actually it is similar to **partition method** done in QuickSort. The given string is the partition element.Once all permutations are generated, the complexity to find the rank for strings with length k would be O(nk). You can generate string permutations using recursion and store them in a linked list. You can pass this **linked list** to the partition method.

Here's the java code to generate all String permutations:

```
 private static int generateStringPermutations(String name,int currIndex) {

        int sum = 0;

        for(int j=name.length()-1;j>=0;j--) {
            for(int i=j-1;((i<j) && (i>currIndex));i--) {

                String swappedString = swapCharsInString(name,i,j);
                list.add(swappedString);
                //System.out.println(swappedString);
                sum++;
                sum = sum + generateStringPermutations(swappedString,i);
            }
        }
        return sum;


    }
```

Edit:

Generating all permutations is costly. If a string contains distinct characters, the rank can be determined without generating all permutations. [**Here's the link**](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=13337667).

This can be extended for cases where there are repeating characters.

Instead of x * (n-1)! which is for distinct cases mentioned as in the link,

For repeating characters it will be:

if there is 1 character which is repeating twice,

x* (n-1)!/2!

Let's take an example. For string abca the combinations are:

aabc,aacb,abac,abca,acab,acba,baac,baca,**bcaa**,caab,**caba**,cbaa (in sorted order)

Total combinations = 4!/2! = 12

if we want to find rank of **'bcaa'** then we know all strings starting with 'a' are before which is 3! = 6.

Note that because 'a' is the starting character, the remaining characters are a,b,c and there are no repetitions so it is 3!.  We also know strings starting with 'ba' will be before which is 2! = 2 so it's **rank is 9**.

Another example. If we want to find the rank of **'caba'**:

All strings starting with a are before = 6.
All strings starting with b are before = 3!/2! = 3 (Because once we choose b, we are left with a,a,c and because there are repetitions it is 3!/2!.
All strings starting with caa will be before which is 1

So the final **rank is 11**.

Comment: Does this only work when there are two repeating (2! in the multinomial theorem's denominator)?  What if we had a word like Bookkeeper?  Would you mind giving us an idea how this would work?

Answer (score 1):

From [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographic-rank-of-a-string/):

> Given a string, find its rank among all its permutations sorted
>   lexicographically. For example, rank of “abc” is 1, rank of “acb” is
>   2, and rank of “cba” is 6.
>
> For simplicity, let us assume that the string does not contain any
>   duplicated characters.
>
> One simple solution is to initialize rank as 1, generate all
>   permutations in lexicographic order. After generating a permutation,
>   check if the generated permutation is same as given string, if same,
>   then return rank, if not, then increment the rank by 1. The time
>   complexity of this solution will be exponential in worst case.
>   Following is an efficient solution.
>
> Let the given string be “STRING”. In the input string, ‘S’ is the
>   first character. There are total 6 characters and 4 of them are
>   smaller than ‘S’. So there can be 4 * 5! smaller strings where first
>   character is smaller than ‘S’, like following
>
> R X X X X X I X X X X X N X X X X X G X X X X X
>
> Now let us Fix S’ and find the smaller strings staring with ‘S’.
>
> Repeat the same process for T, rank is 4*5! + 4*4! +…
>
> Now fix T and repeat the same process for R, rank is 4*5! + 4*4! +
>   3*3! +…
>
> Now fix R and repeat the same process for I, rank is 4*5! + 4*4! +
>   3*3! + 1*2! +…
>
> Now fix I and repeat the same process for N, rank is 4*5! + 4*4! +
>   3*3! + 1*2! + 1*1! +…
>
> Now fix N and repeat the same process for G, rank is 4*5! + 4*4 + 3*3!
>   + 1*2! + 1*1! + 0*0!
>
> Rank = 4*5! + 4*4! + 3*3! + 1*2! + 1*1! + 0*0! = 597
>
> Since the value of rank starts from 1, the final rank = 1 + 597 = 598