# How to count the number of permutations?

Tags: c++, permutation

We are given array-'a' and array-'b' consisting of positive integers.
How can I count all the permutation of array 'a' which are strictly lexicographically smaller than array-'b'?

Arrays can contain as many as 10^5 integers(positive)

Example:

1 2 3 is lexicographically smaller than 3 1 2

1 2 3 is lexicographically smaller than 1 4 5.

I would like the solution to be in C++.

Input : 3

1 2 3

2 1 3

Output : 2

Only permutations 1,2,3 and 1,3,2 are lexicographically smaller than 2 1 3

Comment: I imagine a 10,000-digit number would be difficult to do math with in C++ with built-in integral types

Comment: @PhilM it's closer to 500,000 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just tackle the algorithm.  Once you get that figured out, the implementation should be pretty straightforward.  Does this look like it does what you're looking for?

Pseudo code:

```
function get_perms(a,b)
    #count the number of digits in a that are <b[0]
    count = sum(a<b[0])
    Nperms = (len(a)-1)! #modify this formula as needed
    N = count*Nperms
    if sum(a==b[0]) > 0
        remove 1 b[0] from a
        # repeat the process with the substring assuming a[0]==b[0]
        N += sum(a==b[0])*get_perms(a,b[1:end])
    return N

main()
    get_perms(a,b)
```

Edit:  I did a little searching.  I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482729/string-permutations-rank-data-structure) is what you are looking for.